# Feeding SURF descriptors to Neural Network in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, neural-network

I've got this SURF code for detecting keypoints and descriptors from an image.

```
 Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

extractor.compute( img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
```

Is it possible to use this descriptors as input for neural network? If so, how?

Comment: yes it's possible. but what are you trying to achieve ? classification ? that would need some sort of class-labels as well

Comment: yeah. .  that's what I'm trying to do. how to do that?

Comment: do you *really* need a Neural Network ? opencv has only the MLP type to offer, an SVM is usually faster / more precise.

Comment: i've been using FLANN for matching SURF descriptors, but i think NN works better. i'm making an application to recognize leaf disease base on symptoms anyway. which methods would fit in you think?